# Keyword using namespace in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

is there a logical reason that after the keyword `using namespace`, we can't have a function called for example `myfunction` in the namespace and another function called `myfunction` outside the namespace (with same prototype), but we can have it for variables ( `myvariable` in the namespace and `myvariable` outside it) ?

Comment: Show some example code. Your question is badly formatted, and needs some example.

Comment: The question: why after 'using namespace A' the use of two variables  with the same name (from the namespace A and from the global one) is permitted while the use of two functions with the same name (from the namespace A and from the global one) is forbidden ?

Comment: Yes Liviu. But I think i figured why : the variable is defined inside the block so we know wich variable we are talking about, but a function is defined outside the main, maybe in another file, there's no reason to privilege it over the myfunction in the namespace.

Comment: So you answered your own question. But what does this got to do with Jon's answer ?

Comment: It's to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can have a function with the same name and signature in different namespaces -- that's part of the reason namespaces exist. The only consideration is that if you want to call it you will have to qualify its name.

```
namespace Foo {
    void func();
}

namespace Bar {
    void func();
}

using namespace Foo;
using namespace Bar;

func(); // does not compile -- which func()?

Foo::func(); // ok
Bar::func(); // ok
```